# Understanding the use of one-to-many or many-to-many

Tags: mysql, sql

Little by little I am moving on and understanding sql. Below I have 4 tables. I am trying to work through the “many to many” and “one to many”. Earlier on a similar question I was trying to figure out academies to courses and vice versa. Now it was explained to me that one table was for the course and the other table(academy_course) was for the relationship table where I can store the many-to-many relationships. Do I need to apply the same logic for instructors affiliated with an academy? A unique instructor per academy.

```
CREATE TABLE academy
(
  academy_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(25) not null,
  primary key (id),
 );

CREATE TABLE course
(
course_id     int(11) not null auto_increment,
course_name   VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL ,
primary key (course_id),
); 

CREATE TABLE academy_course
(
  academy_id int(11) not null,
  course_id     int(11) not null ,
  primary key (academy_id, course_id),
  foreign key (academy_id) REFERENCES academy (academy_id) on delete cascade,
  foreign key (course_id) REFERENCES course (course_id) on delete cascade
); 

CREATE TABLE instructors
(
instructor_id      VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL ,
academy_id          INT       NOT NULL , 
instructor_name    VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL ,
primary key (instructor_id),
foreign key (academy_id) REFERENCES academy (academy_id) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: Question isn't very clear, please be more specific

Comment: can an instructor belong to multiple academies?

Comment: @FilipeSilva No, a unique instructor per academy.

Comment: @user2970730. And an academy only has one instructor?

Comment: @FilipeSilva the academy can have several instructors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the instructor only teaches at one academy, then it's easy to just have an academy_id like you have there.

If the instructor can teach at different academies, then yes. You should create a table for that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE academy_instructor
(
  academy_id int(11) not null,
  instructor_id     int(11) not null ,
  primary key (academy_id, instructor_id),
  foreign key (academy_id) REFERENCES academy (academy_id) on delete cascade,
  foreign key (instructor_id) REFERENCES instructor (instructor_id) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: would I need to add `instructor_id` as foreign key to `academy_course` table?

Comment: No. That isn't needed.

Comment: As mentioned above the the academy can have several instructors. Is there any additional change need to be made because of that?

Comment: Then no. I Would do it the way you have right now. Have academy_id as foreign key on the instructor table

Answer (score 0):

If one each academy has only one instructor then I would consider adding
`instructor_id` to the `academy_course` table.

Comment: would I need to add `instructor_id` as foreign key to `academy_course` table?

Answer (score 0):

If the same instructor can teach at different academies (which does happen), then it would be a many-to-many.  If no instructor does that, it would be a one-to-many.